# How to use Expression Blend 4 to Edit XAML file from VS2010 F# Project?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, f#, expression-blend

I am not sure if this is possible but I want to create an F# Application in Visual Studio 2010. I then want to create the WPF GUI via XAML files which I edit via Expression Blend 4.

Blend does not allow F# Projects to be created.  VS2010 does not allow XAML files to be created.

I have followed the steps here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273078.aspx

However when I open the Solution in Blend I can't see the XAML files in 'design' mode.

Is this possible?

Comment: The fact that you can't add XAML files to F# project is quite annoying, but you can do that by renaming the file or by using "Add Existing Item". Is that's what your project contains? If you look at the equivalent of "Solution Explorer" in Blend, then you should see all files in the project...

Comment: I created a file in VS as a 'text' file and saved as sample.xaml. I then used the 'Add Existing Item' to select the XAML file from within Blend.  I can then see the file within the project and I can edit the XAML code - but I can't view/edit in 'design' mode the option is greyed out - as are most menu options.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that to make the XAML file editable in Design view of Blend I had to change from the default F# Application (Console) to F# Application (Windows) and secondly add the PresentationFoundation.dll as a resource.

From the fsproj file.

```
-     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
-     <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Blend generally doesn't like XAML files that are set to Resource.  It expects XAML files to be Page or Content (caveat emptor: no reference, just my experience).  Unless you need the XAML to be with the F#, I'd put it in a separate WPF control library project.